# Symfony 3 setting up a test database

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I'm trying to set up a testing suite for my Symfony 3 app, and I'm wondering what the correct method for setting up the test database is. I've found this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-testing-symfony-apps-with-a-disposable-database/), but it doesn't actually explain how to add fixtures programmatically.

Also, it appears their example sets up the test database for every test.

Is there a way to setup a test database which is automatically loaded with fixtures when `phpunit` is run? The official documentation is kind of [sparse](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html)

Answer (score 2):

Symfony has different environments you can operate in. By default those are prod(production), dev(developement) and test. Although it may not be exactly what you want, you can configure different config, paramaters, routes and so on for each environment. Read the official documentation for more info but yeah, you can setup your parameters.yml file for test mode which could have a different database configured there.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

If you extend your TestCases from `KernelTestCase` or `WebTestCase`, basically extend from `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` you have methods like `setUpBeforeClass()` or `setUp()` which are run by PhpUnit before your test/test cases is/are executed.

Use this to e.g. create your fixtures, load your SQL file or whatever and however you might require your prerequisites for your tests.